# Expanding brackets and collecting like terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the expression $2x^2 + (2x-3) - (2x-3)^2 = 8$.

For this I get $2x^2 + (2x-3) - (4x^2-12x+9) - 8 = 0$

which becomes $2x^2 + 2 + 10 = 0$.

However the solutions say that the expression shoul simplify to $x^2 - 7x + 10 = 0$.

So what have I done wrong ?

Comment: You didn't combine the $x^1$ terms correctly nor the constant terms.  Note the negative sign in front of the second set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 2x^2+(2x-3)-(4x^2-12x+9)-8 \\[2ex]
 &= 2x^2+2x-3-4x^2+12x-9-8 \\[2ex]
 &= 2x^2-4x^2+2x+12x-3-9-8 \\[2ex]
 &= -2x^2+14x-20
\end{align}$$

The steps there are removing parenthesis by distributing the $+$ and the $-$, rearranging terms, and combining like terms.

Divide both sides of that by $-2$ and you will see that the answer key is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You got the following correctly:

$$2x^2+(2x-3)-(4x^2-12x+9)-8=0$$

But the next step should be to distribute the negative sign are remove parenthesis.

$$2x^2+2x-3-4x^2+12x-9-8=0$$

$$-2x^2+14x-20=0$$

Divide both sides by $-2$ and you should get...

$$x^2-7x+10=0$$